# difference between ^ vs ^.*$ in Rewrite rule apache in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

What is the difference between `^` vs `^.*$` in the third line of both the expressions. Are they same or different from each other

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^  %1 [L,R=301]
```

and

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
 RewriteRule ^.*$  %1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Both will have same effect but just using `^` (start anchor) will be a bit more efficient

Comment: Reason for that is that the rule is not at all interested in what is matched and how in this case. Which is why the actual matching pattern is irrelevant. Which is why a more simple pattern makes more sense _in this specific example_ ... There are other situations where that is not the case though, typically if the rewriting rule reuses something that has been captured via that pattern

Comment: I am unable to understand how this anchor ^ is more efficient in this case as compared to ^.*$ even when its matching nothing and just asserting a starting position

Answer (score 2):

The net result in these two examples is the same, but they are technically different and `^` is more efficient in this case.

In both of these rules you simply need the `RewriteRule` directive to be successful for everything and both regex achieve that.

`^` - This regex simply asserts the start-of-string anchor, so it is successful for everything, but matches nothing. (The `$0` backreference is empty.)

**UPDATE:** For example, given a request for `/abc`, then the approx steps involved are:

1. `^` asserts the start of the URL-path.
2. No more symbols in the regex. The regex is successful. Nothing has been matched in the requested URL-path. The `$0` backreference is empty. **DONE**

`^.*$` - This regex matches anything and everything, so it is successful for everything *and matches everything*. Since it actually matches *everything*, the `$0` backreference stores the entire URL-path that is matched. If you simply need to be successful then this is less efficient as it traverses the entire URL-path. Incidentally, this is the same as simply `.*` because regex is *greedy* by default.

**UPDATE:** For example, given a request for `/abc`, then the approx steps involved are:

1. `^` asserts the start of the URL-path.
2. `.` matches `a` in `abc`.
3. `*` quantifier repeats the previous match 0 or more times (greedy).
4. `.` matches `b` in `abc`.
5. `*` quantifier repeats the previous match 0 or more times (greedy).
6. `.` matches `c` in `abc`.
7. `*` quantifier repeats the previous match 0 or more times (greedy).
8. `.` does not match anything (fails) since we have reached the end of the URL-path.
9. `$` asserts the end of the URL-path.
10. No more symbols in the regex. The regex is successful. The entire URL-path has been matched by traversing through the URL-path. The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path. **DONE**

However...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
> RewriteRule ^  %1 [L,R=301]
> ```

This could actually be made more efficient since the 2nd `RewriteCond` directive is not required. This check should be made in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead, to avoid a filesystem check on every request, not just requests that end in a slash (which is all that's required). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* is processed first, before any of the conditions, so you should do as much processing here as possible. Note the addition of the slash prefix on the *substitution* string, which is missing from the `$1` backreference. (The slash is otherwise part of the `%1` backreference - as you used previously - because the `REQUEST_URI` server variable starts with a slash.)

Comment: I am unable to understand how this anchor ^  is more efficient in this case as compared to ^.*$ even when its matching nothing and just asserting a starting position

Comment: I've added an example in each case showing the approximate steps involved when requesting a URL of the form `/abc`.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite really cleared the ambiguity in my mind..:D

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkmark next to the answer below the voting arrows (to help other readers and to remove the question from the unanswered question queue). Thanks, much appreciated. :)